# Android Navigation Drawer Content Frame Cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I am using the following code to implement a simple navigation drawer based on the sample given in the Android Developers site.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] mDrawerItems;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.graph_array);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_drawer);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navDrawer);
        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description, R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }


        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerItems));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        //Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        //Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        //fragment.setArguments(args);

        if (position == 0) {
            Fragment frag1 = new Fragment1();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, frag1).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mDrawerItems[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else if (position == 1) {

        }
    }



        @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.graph_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                    "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error saying "content_frame cannot be resolved". How do I fix this ?

EDIT :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.shivam.signalprocessing1.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground="#4000">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="144dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/material_wallpaper" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view_drawer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/image_view"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.example.shivam.signalprocessing1.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks !

Comment: you have any layout with `content_frame` id in xml ?

Comment: Post your XML file (activity_main.xml) please.

Comment: Check updated question. I have not used a frame layout, which is why I am getting the error. But then what do I use in the JAVA code in place of that ?

Answer (score -1):

Change the id of the frame... its normally container... But change it to content_frame and you are good.